# Cannot exit script after using ssh -t -t

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I am running a shell script which will `ssh` to multiple servers, connect to the databases on them, run some queries and then exit.
The script is like below:

```
#!/bin/ksh  
for i in server1 server2 server3  
do  
ssh -t -t $i 'sudo su - oracle && bash -s' < /path/r1.sh  
done  
exit
```

I have to force tty using -t -t because somehow request_tty -t does not work on all servers. The script /path/r1.sh is as below:

```
ALL_DATABASES=`cat /etc/oratab|grep -v "^#"|grep -v "N$"|cut -f1 -d: -s`  
for DB in $ALL_DATABASES  
do  
   unset  TWO_TASK  
   export ORACLE_SID=$DB  
   export ORACLE_HOME=`grep "^${DB}:" /etc/oratab|cut -d: -f2 -s`  
   export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH  
   echo "---> Database $ORACLE_SID, using home $ORACLE_HOME"  
   sqlplus "/ as sysdba" <<-EOF  

select name from v\$database;  
exit;  
EOF  
done
```

The problem is that the script runs only on the first server and then does not exit. Only CTRL+C helps but it kills the entire script. Could you suggest any better way to integrate both scripts?

Comment: FWIW, I am not sure the problem is `ssh -t -t`; I am able to `ssh -t -t host.example.com 'sudo command'` and it works as expected.

Comment: I agree now that ssh -t -t doesn't seem to be the problem, as I ran a few other scripts using ssh -t -t and they ran as expected. I guess it is the way I am executing the script. Could you guide me how I can integrate both scripts? I have mentioned both scripts in my post now. Thanks